# Button takes two clicks to make action on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem where my hamburger icon takes two clicks on page refresh to start working. I am using code shown below where i want to change left property of my navigation when user clicks hamburger icon. It works fine but it takes two clicks to start working properly whenever the page is refreshed.

```
let hamburgerIcon = document.getElementById('hamburger-icon');
let asideNavigation = document.getElementById('nav-list-wrapper');


hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (asideNavigation.style.left === "-100vw") {
    asideNavigation.style.left = "0";
  } else {
    asideNavigation.style.left = "-100vw";
  }
})
```

Comment: May you share the CSS of the `nav-list-wrapper`?

Comment: perhaps `asideNavigation.style.left` is initially blank (no value) - so, same as `0` ... so the first time it just get set to 0 - which means, no change - try inverting the logic ... `if (asideNavigation.style.left !== "-100vw") asideNavigation.style.left = "-100vw" else asideNavigation.style.left = "0"`